# Unable to start React Native application. TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'domelementtype_1.ElementType.Tag')

Tags: expo, react-native, typeerror, node-modules

I have been working on a React Native application for awhile, but suddenly am unable to run it. The problem first occurred after installing a new package; I uninstalled the package but I'm still getting the same error. I also tried reverting to an old commit, but it didn't work.

The app seems to start up correctly correctly using `expo start`, but when I try to run it on my phone I get this error:

```
Unable to start your application. Please refer to https://expo.fyi/no-registered-application for more information.
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:117:10 in registerWarning
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:63:8 in warnImpl
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:36:4 in console.warn
- node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:18:4 in warn
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:200:6 in runApplication
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'domelementtype_1.ElementType.Tag')
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
- node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
- node_modules\expo-error-recovery\build\ErrorRecovery.fx.js:9:32 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:164:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

Any idea what is going on here? I am new to stackoverflow and React Native, so please let me know if there is other information I should provide.

Answer (score 0):

couple days ago i also recieved that error on React for no apparent reason,
with exact same issues.
I replaced `'domelementtype_1.ElementType.Tag'` with `'domelementtype_1.Tag'`,
it worked for me i am still not sure about consequences of this.
But at least you will be able to start the app.

Comment: Where do you see 'domelementtype_1.ElementType.Tag'? I can't find where to change it.